# Unable to import spring boot maven project in IntelliJ IDEA - IDE not responding after importing

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, intellij-idea

I recently started working on a new mini spring-boot project (I'm very new to this) for learning purposes. But I'm finding some problem in setting up the IntelliJ IDE. First I downloaded the zip folder from the spring initializr site, and then I tried to import the extracted folder in the IDE. But no subsequent dialogue boxes get displayed after I select 'Maven' from 'Import project from external model' dialogue box. IDE isn’t responding after that. I don't know how to proceed. No error prompts or anything is popping up. I have installed Maven separately and the version is 3.6.3.

```
C:\Users\User>mvn --version
Apache Maven 3.6.3 (cecedd343002696d0abb50b32b541b8a6ba2883f)
Maven home: C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.6.3-bin\apache-maven-3.6.3\bin\..
Java version: 1.8.0_231, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_231\jre
Default locale: en_IN, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 8.1", version: "6.3", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"
```

The java version is 1.8:

```
C:\Users\User>java -version
java version "1.8.0_231"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_231-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.231-b11, mixed mode)
```

Edit: I just realized that I was trying to import the extracted folder but the main folder was inside it! It's solved. Thanks for the answers and comments. :)

Comment: have you tried to create the project from within IntelliJ? Just open IntelliJ, go to new project, select the Spring Initializer and select the components you want. No need to download the zip then. Another thing that may cause problems, is that your path to MAVEN_HOME contains a space (Program Files). Youmight try to install maven to a folder that has nos spaces in the name

Comment: But if that path has space problem then the version won't be displayed properly? Do we have to create a separate MAVEN_HOME variable? I have only added the path to the existing path variable.

Comment: Have you tried importing it following these steps: `File` -> 'New' -> 'Project from Existing Sources` -> Go to location of you Spring Boot app and select the `pom.xml` file?

Answer (score 1):

You can either use built-in IntelliJ Idea (Ultimate version) support for Spring Boot using File -> New -> Project and choose Spring Initializer.

Or you can just download the ZIP, unzip it somewhere and simply open pom.xml file in IntelliJ Idea and choose to "Open as project". If this doesn't help, then on the right side of IntelliJ Idea there should be button "Maven", which opens Maven section and there normally should be visible your project. If it's not, then click on the "+" button to add your project as Maven project. Or press "SHIFT" button twice and select "Add Maven Project".

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the answer. I just realized that I was trying to import the extracted folder but the main folder was inside it!